# Bash: Replacing "" with newline character, using sed or tr

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I'm trying to format output in a way that inserts newline characters after each 'line', with lines denoted by double quotes (""). The quotes themselves are temporary and to be stripped in a later step.

Input:

```
"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"
```

Output:

```
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
```

I've tried:

```
sed 's/""/\n/'
sed 's/""/\/g'
tr '""' '\n'
```

But tr seems to replace every quote character and sed seems to insert \n as text instead of a newline. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"' |awk -v RS='""' '{$1=$1} {gsub(/"/,"")}1'
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
```

or using `sed`:

```
 echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"' |sed -e 's/""/\n/' -e 's/"//g'   # OR sed -e 's/""/\n/;s/"//g'
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
```

`awk` solution: Here the default record separator is changed from new line to `""`. So `awk` will consider the EOL when it hits `""`.

`sed` solution: Here first `""` are converted into new line and second replacement is to remove `"` from each line.

Answer (score 3):

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat file.txt
"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ sed 's/""/\n/' file.txt | tr -d '"'
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
```

Comment: `tr` is  unnecessary here.You can finish with `sed` alone like `echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"'| sed 's/""/\n/g;s/"//g'`

Comment: Indeed. Was just tweaking OPs original attempt. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dealing with POSIX `sed`, which does not have support for the `\n` notation. Insert an actual new-line into the pattern, either:

```
sed 's/""/\
/'
```

Or:

```
sed 's/""/\'$'\n''/'
```

E.g.:

```
sed 's/""/\
/' | tr -d \"
```

Output:

```
a,1,aa
b,2,bb
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by George Vasiliou if you have perl you could use:

```
>  echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"' | perl -pe 's/""/"\n"/g;s/"//g'
```

This avoids the non portable sed problem.

Or for a crappy hack version.

Replace the "" with another character and then use tr (since tr should work with \n) to replace it with \n instead then remove the single " after.

So you can get the "" replaced with newline like this:

```
sed 's/""/#/g' | tr '#' '\n'
```

Then the rest follows:

```
> echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"'| sed 's/""/#/g' | tr '#' '\n' | sed 's/\"//g'
```

Comment: echo '"a",1,"aa""b",2,"bb"'| sed 's/\"\"/\n/g' | sed 's/\"//g' still only outputs 1 line for me

Comment: Thats weird, it works for me. I'll take another look.

Comment: see the post from thor, I think he's probably on to something

Comment: When `sed` does not work as expected (i.e you use a GNU sed while OP uses probably a non gnu sed) there is a portable solution avoiding sed brainpuzzle : replace `sed` with `perl -pe` keeping all the rest code identical as it was used in sed command. With `perl -pe` will work the same way in any platform that has perl installed.